# Webpack build failing with Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\absolutepath\MyApp\MyApp'

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, webpack

I'm pretty new to webpack and going round in circles trying to resolve an error in the build. I want the build to work regardless of my current directory, so I've been trying to use path, context, __dir in a bunch of configurations and it still fails unless my current directory is the root of the app. Any guidance would be massively appreciated!

This is how my folders are structured:

```
MyApp-django
├─MyApp
│    ├───src  
│    │     │   index.tsx
│    │     └───components
│    │           └───App.tsx
│    └── static
│           └───frontend
│                   main.js
├─tsconfig.json
└─webpack.config.json
```

This is my webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "MyApp"),
  entry: {
    app: [
      path.join(__dirname, "./MyApp/frontend/src/index.tsx"),
      path.join(__dirname, "./MyApp/frontend/src/components/App.tsx"),
    ],
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./MyApp/frontend/static/frontend"),
  },
};
```

my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strictNullChecks": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
    },
    "include": ["./MyApp/frontend/src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
    
  }
```

and finally the error I receive, if my cd is any directory other than root:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\absolutepath\MyApp-django\MyApp'
resolve './src' in 'C:\absolutepath\MyApp-django\MyApp'
  using description file: C:\absolutepath\MyApp-django\package.json (relative path: ./MyApp)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: C:\absolutepath\MyApp-django\package.json (relative path: ./MyApp/src)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\absolutepath\MyApp\MyApp\src doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\absolutepath\MyApp\MyApp\src.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\absolutepath\MyApp\MyApp\src.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\absolutepath\MyApp\MyApp\src.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\absolutepath\MyApp\MyApp\src doesn't exist
```

Comment: well you need to be at the root for it to work, your paths are relative to the current directory

Comment: I tested it even with absolute paths and it still results in the same error. Most of the time I need to be in the 2nd `MyApp` directory, is there a way I could tweak it to at least work for that context consistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple solution that works for me. Kept the config files as-is and wrote a new script in `package.json`, allowing me to build from the root directory and return to my working directory.

```
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "pushd . && webpack && popd"
  }
```

```
// terminal
npm run dev
```